# ./ssh-keygen: 1: ./ssh-keygen: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")

Tags: linux, ssh, cross-compiling

I am using openssh-6.4p1 for ssh and sftp support and sdk is ipnc_rdk_dm36x_5.1 and compiler is arm-arago-linux-gnueabi- 
when i am configuring openssh with below command

```
./configure --prefix=$(TARGET_FS)/usr --with-libs 
--with-zlib=$(TARGET_FS)/usr --with-ssl-dir=$(TARGET_FS)/usr 
--disable-strip --disable-etc-default-login CC=$(BUILD_TOOL_PREFIX)gcc 
AR=$(BUILD_TOOL_PREFIX)ar LD=$(BUILD_TOOL_PREFIX)gcc RANLIB=$(BUILD_TOOL_PREFIX)ranlib --host=arm-linux-gnueabi
```

and then compiling and Installing

when i am installing, i am getting below error

```
./ssh-keygen: 1: ./ssh-keygen: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
./ssh-keygen: 1: ./ssh-keygen: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

can any one help me please...

thanks in advance